# preload images on javascript (React, Jquery) app, images loaded twice

Tags: javascript, image, dom, browser-cache, preload

- **Please look at EDIT 3 below, as I figured out that it is not an issue with React but with the browser's chaching mechanism.**

I'm trying to create an app that creates some simple carousel out of given array of images url. I've written a module that helps me to invoke a callback once all the images are loaded, this is how it look:

ImagesLoader.js

```
export default {
    // a module that loads an array of images urls and when completes
    // calls a callback with the images elements array

    load(imagesUrlsArray, callback){
        const imagesLoaded = [];
        imagesUrlsArray.map((url) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                imagesLoaded.push(img);
                if(imagesUrlsArray.length === imagesLoaded.length){
                    callback(imagesLoaded);
                }
            };
            img.src = url;
        });
    }
}
```

I know I can use promises and resolve once all urls are loaded, and no check for errors right now.

Here is where my component updates the state with the images retriveed from the module above:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ImagesLoader.load(this.props.images, (loadedImages) => {
        const imagesStateData = this.calculateImagesStateData(loadedImages);
        this.setState(Object.assign({},
            imagesStateData,
            {
                loaded: true,
                loadedImages: loadedImages
            }
        ));
    });
}
```

What happens is when I click the next or previous button (look at the screenshot below) each time the image loaded again, I can't understand why.

*this is the first time I do such thing with reactjs, with jquery had no problems*

[image: Network tab on chrome]

Here is how I pass the images urls:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    var images = [
      "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/excellent-love-quotes-wallpaper-hd.jpg",
      "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/My-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-Wallpaper-HD-Landscapes1.jpg",
      "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/58/01/02/5801020fea36221ffba33633f99a7d81.jpg",
      "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/pier_1080.jpg",
      "http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/wallpaper-black-hd-hd-wallpapers.jpg",
      "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dvg12YJKaKg/UnVfkMke7jI/AAAAAAAAUaU/O86x5FMgEuk/s1600/longcat.gif"
    ];

    var settings = {
      autoPlay: true,
      arrows: true
    };

    return (
      <Layout>
        <ReactCarousel images={images} width={500} height={300} settings={settings}/>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
managed to give a short example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObyRPX , what I could see from building this example is if I don't use the `ImageItem` component and render a simple `<img src='image.src'/>` element it works good, so I guess my problem is with the `ImageItem` component.

EDIT 2:
this is pretty weird http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBpdjx here I just changed it so ImageItem renderes image element rather than background image on a div and it works as expected. Can anyone explain what is the difference?

EDIT 3:

Apparently this is happening not only on react apps but on jquery app aswell, have a look here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmvyPZ

Again when I try to load the image as background-image property of the css, the browser doesn't cache the image and  load it twice.

Comment: For me it works fine: `https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/hxcuruL6/`. Maybe you have some other relations with this issue? Looks like this component will be render twice

Comment: It renders the second time only when I click the next/previous button. The thing is that it loads the images only twice so if I continue clicking the next button, in the next round of the images display it is already loaded and renders to DOM without loading time, as expected. I'll try to my a codepen/jsfiddle example right now. thanks though

Comment: Ok, managed to give a short example. `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObyRPX` , what I could see from building this example is if I don't use the `ImageItem` component and render a simple `<img src='image.src'/>` element it works good, so I guess my problem is with the `ImageItem` component. Can you help me figure out what is wrong there? EDITED MY QUESTION

Comment: Do a small test: `ImagesLoader` loads images directly in your slider-wrapper (what you do normal here `ImageItem`). So the plan: `enable loader` then `load images directly in your slider <ul> list` then `hide loader`. I tested it quickly and it works (but i tested it with your hint to load the images not in `background: url(...)` but rather like your prefer `<img src="img.jpg/>`. As you see later in Network tab (inspector) you will only see images from initator "react.min.js". Im not sure but i think react will something other like the regular way like jquery preloading images.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty weird `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBpdjx` here I just changed it so and image element rather than background image and it works as expected. Can anyone explain what is the difference?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Eventually I used `<img src="..." />` didn't manage to get it work with background image

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same issue. The image gets loaded again because the browser is not holding a reference to the image that you have loaded.

All I did was create a global array and push all the images to the array.

Now, this array is global and the browser has to maintain the array until the whole app gets destroyed.

```
var allImages = [];

function loadImages(imageUrls) {
imageUrls.forEach((q) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = q;
    allImages.push(img);
});}
```

After this, I was able to load the images on other pages, even when offline.

Comment: this answer has 0 upvotes and 0 comments but it totally just saved my life lol

Answer (score 0):

Chrome shows 2 image requests in `devtool` for one image. Try to uncheck `disable cache` option in the `network` tab.

[image: Disable cache]